# How to config Char in node red using CharType

Tags: charts, node-red

I would like to be able to modifiy my Char type with my payload. I have two button one for the stats of the last hour and another one for the stats for the last 24 hours.

I would like when I click on the button for the 60 minute it will be a line graph and when I click on 24 hours it will switch to bar graph.

Here is my actual code

```
[
    {
        "id": "81d13b556483bbf6",
        "type": "ui_chart",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "name": "test1",
        "group": "2d22592eeb22de83",
        "order": 1,
        "width": 22,
        "height": 11,
        "label": "Entrée Électrique Groupe  LML",
        "chartType": "line",
        "legend": "true",
        "xformat": "HH:mm:ss",
        "interpolate": "linear",
        "nodata": "no data",
        "dot": true,
        "ymin": "",
        "ymax": "",
        "removeOlder": "3",
        "removeOlderPoints": "60",
        "removeOlderUnit": "60",
        "cutout": 0,
        "useOneColor": true,
        "useUTC": false,
        "colors": [
            "#1f77b4",
            "#aec7e8",
            "#ff7f0e",
            "#2ca02c",
            "#98df8a",
            "#d62728",
            "#ff9896",
            "#9467bd",
            "#c5b0d5"
        ],
        "outputs": 1,
        "useDifferentColor": false,
        "className": "",
        "x": 1790,
        "y": 640,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "ba92472b5bc0535c",
        "type": "change",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "name": "",
        "rules": [
            {
                "t": "set",
                "p": "payload",
                "pt": "msg",
                "to": "[{    \"labels\": [$distinct(payload.temps)],\t    \"series\": [$distinct(payload.tag)],\t    \"data\":[[$each(payload{temps:Valeur}, function($val){$val})]]\t}]\t",
                "tot": "jsonata"
            }
        ],
        "action": "",
        "property": "",
        "from": "",
        "to": "",
        "reg": false,
        "x": 1640,
        "y": 640,
        "wires": [
            [
                "81d13b556483bbf6",
                "1ea4592424e3b769"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "552e726ef49593ba",
        "type": "join",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "name": "",
        "mode": "auto",
        "build": "array",
        "property": "payload",
        "propertyType": "msg",
        "key": "topic",
        "joiner": "\\n",
        "joinerType": "str",
        "accumulate": false,
        "timeout": "",
        "count": "",
        "reduceRight": false,
        "reduceExp": "",
        "reduceInit": "",
        "reduceInitType": "",
        "reduceFixup": "",
        "x": 1490,
        "y": 640,
        "wires": [
            [
                "ba92472b5bc0535c"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "044122efefe5e6f5",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "name": "function 14",
        "func": "var lebels = msg.payload.temps\nmsg.payload.temps = String(lebels); \nmsg.payload.tag = \"test\"\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 1330,
        "y": 640,
        "wires": [
            [
                "4cd731b7da9e6497",
                "552e726ef49593ba"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "7dd1a452137b7191",
        "type": "split",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "name": "",
        "splt": "\\n",
        "spltType": "str",
        "arraySplt": 1,
        "arraySpltType": "len",
        "stream": false,
        "addname": "",
        "x": 1170,
        "y": 640,
        "wires": [
            [
                "044122efefe5e6f5"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "14bf448b1c5277bb",
        "type": "MSSQL",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "mssqlCN": "029fdb9c678d84cb",
        "name": "",
        "outField": "payload",
        "returnType": 0,
        "throwErrors": 1,
        "query": "SELECT AVG(Valeur) AS Valeur, \r\n       CONCAT(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(day, MyDate)), 2), ':', \r\n              RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hour, MyDate)), 2)\r\n       ) AS temps\r\nFROM dbo.General\r\nWHERE MyDate >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AND Tag LIKE  '{{{payload}}}' AND Equipement LIKE 'EntreElectrique'\r\nGROUP BY CONCAT(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(day, MyDate)), 2), ':', RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hour, MyDate)), 2))\r\nORDER BY temps\r\n",
        "modeOpt": "queryMode",
        "modeOptType": "query",
        "queryOpt": "payload",
        "queryOptType": "editor",
        "paramsOpt": "queryParams",
        "paramsOptType": "none",
        "rows": "rows",
        "rowsType": "msg",
        "params": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 600,
        "wires": [
            [
                "7dd1a452137b7191"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "80b322d805e85ddb",
        "type": "MSSQL",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "mssqlCN": "029fdb9c678d84cb",
        "name": "",
        "outField": "payload",
        "returnType": 0,
        "throwErrors": 1,
        "query": "SELECT AVG(Valeur) AS Valeur, \r\n       CONCAT(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hour, MyDate)), 2), ':', \r\n              RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(minute, MyDate)), 2)\r\n       ) AS temps\r\nFROM dbo.General\r\nWHERE MyDate >= DATEADD(hour, -1, GETDATE()) AND Tag LIKE  '{{{payload}}}' AND Equipement LIKE 'EntreElectrique'\r\nGROUP BY CONCAT(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hour, MyDate)), 2), ':', RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(minute, MyDate)), 2))\r\nORDER BY temps\r\n",
        "modeOpt": "queryMode",
        "modeOptType": "query",
        "queryOpt": "payload",
        "queryOptType": "editor",
        "paramsOpt": "queryParams",
        "paramsOptType": "none",
        "rows": "rows",
        "rowsType": "msg",
        "params": [],
        "x": 980,
        "y": 540,
        "wires": [
            [
                "7dd1a452137b7191"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "59ac8b2b32f26664",
        "type": "change",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "name": "",
        "rules": [
            {
                "t": "set",
                "p": "payload",
                "pt": "msg",
                "to": "DropDownMenu2",
                "tot": "flow"
            }
        ],
        "action": "",
        "property": "",
        "from": "",
        "to": "",
        "reg": false,
        "x": 680,
        "y": 540,
        "wires": [
            [
                "80b322d805e85ddb"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "135e25359841e246",
        "type": "change",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "name": "",
        "rules": [
            {
                "t": "set",
                "p": "payload",
                "pt": "msg",
                "to": "DropDownMenu2",
                "tot": "flow"
            }
        ],
        "action": "",
        "property": "",
        "from": "",
        "to": "",
        "reg": false,
        "x": 680,
        "y": 600,
        "wires": [
            [
                "14bf448b1c5277bb"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "66fe73cbf2d65d3a",
        "type": "ui_button",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "name": "",
        "group": "2d22592eeb22de83",
        "order": 4,
        "width": 11,
        "height": 1,
        "passthru": false,
        "label": "24 Heures",
        "tooltip": "",
        "color": "",
        "bgcolor": "",
        "className": "",
        "icon": "",
        "payload": "TensionBatterie",
        "payloadType": "str",
        "topic": "payloadtag",
        "topicType": "msg",
        "x": 410,
        "y": 600,
        "wires": [
            [
                "135e25359841e246"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "40aa6c2a1edadbf2",
        "type": "ui_button",
        "z": "38b4959d8b6fda96",
        "name": "",
        "group": "2d22592eeb22de83",
        "order": 2,
        "width": 11,
        "height": 1,
        "passthru": false,
        "label": "60 Minutes",
        "tooltip": "",
        "color": "",
        "bgcolor": "",
        "className": "",
        "icon": "",
        "payload": "TensionBatterie",
        "payloadType": "str",
        "topic": "payload",
        "topicType": "msg",
        "x": 410,
        "y": 540,
        "wires": [
            [
                "59ac8b2b32f26664"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2d22592eeb22de83",
        "type": "ui_group",
        "name": "Entrée Électrique",
        "tab": "0c634fef27455e8d",
        "order": 1,
        "disp": true,
        "width": "22",
        "collapse": true,
        "className": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "029fdb9c678d84cb",
        "type": "MSSQL-CN",
        "tdsVersion": "7_4",
        "name": "test",
        "server": "PC-136\\SQLEXPRESS",
        "port": "1433",
        "encyption": true,
        "trustServerCertificate": true,
        "database": "Node_red",
        "useUTC": true,
        "connectTimeout": "15000",
        "requestTimeout": "150000",
        "cancelTimeout": "5000",
        "pool": "5",
        "parseJSON": false,
        "enableArithAbort": true
    },
    {
        "id": "0c634fef27455e8d",
        "type": "ui_tab",
        "name": "Graphique",
        "icon": "dashboard",
        "order": 6,
        "disabled": false,
        "hidden": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not dynamically change a chart time with node-red-dashboard.

Comment: thanks, sadly you confirm what I thought...